# Use of function types or closures to dynamically call a function

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I did some research but I could not solve my problem. Maybe due to my bad Swift know how :(

I do have a switch case. In each case I do the same things but call a different function. Is there a good way to move the duplicate logic outside the switch case and just set the needed function in the case block? The parameters of each function are also the same.

Here is an example code:

```
switch index {
case 0:
    //do some stuff
    myFuncCase_1(onCompletion: { 
       //do some async stuff
    })
    //do some more stuff
case 1:
    //do some same stuff
    myFuncCase_2(onCompletion: { 
       //do some same async stuff
    })
    //do some more same stuff
default: break
}
```

So, the only difference is the name of the function I will call.
Is there a good solution with closures or function types?

Comment: Is `//do some async stuff` code is same or diffrent ?

Comment: use multiple matches in same case. In your code you can use
case 0,1,.... what ever matches have the same logic and call single generic function from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have some functions defined somewhere, with identical signatures.

```
func somefunc(callback:()->()) -> () {
    // work, work, work
    callback()
}
func otherfunc(callback:()->()) -> () {
    // work, work, work
    callback()
}
```

These functions have the type `(()->())->()`

This is a closure that takes one parameter and returns Void. The type of the one parameter is a closure that takes nothing and returns Void.

Note the parameter label (i.e, *callback*) is not part of the type.

Then you could do something like this:

```
var myfunc: (()->())->()
switch index {
case 0:
    myfunc = somefunc
case 1:
    myfunc = otherfunc
default:
    myfunc = { _ in }
}
// do some same stuff
myfunc() {
    // do some same async stuff
}
// do some more same stuff
```

The default case just creates an anonymous closure that doesn't do anything. You can't simply break on the default case because `myfunc` would be uninitialized upon use.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a nested function to achieve this.

```
typealias Callback = (() -> Void)!

func someFunc() {
    func switchExecution(_ function: ((_ completion: Callback) -> Void)!) {
        //do some stuff

        function {
            //do async stuff
        }

        //do some more stuff
    }

    switch index {
    case 0:
        switchExecution(myFuncCase_1)
    case 1:
        switchExecution(myFuncCase_2)
    default: break
    }
}
```